# How i can return the original data of this promise data

Tags: javascript, arrays

The problem is when i set the value in the array from the each promise, the value not return when forEach finish in the array.

```
let works = [];
    const imgsUrl = saveImages(imgs);
    imgsUrl.map(async (img) => {
        img.then(value => {
            works = [...works, value];
        })

    });
```

Someone any idea, thanks by the way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't quite a [mcve] so it's hard to infer your intent, but are you looking for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) by chance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) (you're (ab)using `map` as essentially a `forEach` here)

Comment: …and also don't mix `then` with `await`.

Comment: You might be looking for `const works = (await Promise.all(saveImages(imgs))).flat()`, but really the `saveImages` function should do the `Promise.all` already and return a promise for an array, not an array of promises.

Comment: Thanks, Promise.all help me to return an array data